# Edit Control showing a readout of Slider Control's position

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I have created a `Slider Control` and an `Edit Control` that are linked, so that moving the slider changes the edit box's text, and manually editing the text moves the slider. For the most part it works but after I release the mouse button when dragging the `Slider`, the `Edit Control` shows 0. While I'm dragging it does show the correct value.

I can partially fix the problem by adding an `if(nPos != 0)` clause, which stops that happening. However when I click to move the `Slider` rather than drag, the `Edit Control` doesn't update.

Do I need a different handler for when the `Slider` is clicked rather than dragged? Or am I doing something wrong?

```
// Updates slider when value is changed in the Edit Box
void CProject1Dlg::OnChangeEdit1() {
    SLIDER_1.SetPos(GetDlgItemInt(IDC_EDIT1) / 1000);
}


// Slider horizontal scroll handler
void CProject1Dlg::OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
    if (nPos != 0) {
        SetDlgItemInt(IDC_EDIT1, nPos * 1000);
    }

    CDialogEx::OnHScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you try extracting the position of the slider directly with [GetPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/1y934e5b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rather than using the `nPos` parameter?

Comment: Don't really understand why it should make a difference, but it worked, thanks.